# How to create "cmd" function in Python?

Tags: python, shell, command-line

I'm trying to create a function which returns output as the command would be written into the command line in **Windows** or **Linux**?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
def cmd_simulator(commands):
    #some code

cmd_simulator("date")

- Thu Jan 28 12:18:05 EST 2016
```

or Windows:

```
cmd_simulator("date")

- The current date is: Thu 01/28/2016
- Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy)
```

Comment: Do you want to delegate your commands to the console shell?

Comment: [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) may be be useful to you.

Comment: `cmd_simulator=lambda cmd:os.popen(cmd).read();print cmd_simulator("date")`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `subprocess` module in order to deal with command lines inside a python script.
If the only thing you need is to get the output of your command, then use `subprocess.check_output(cmd)`.

`cmd` is a sequence (python list) of program arguments. So, if your command only contains one word (such as `date`), it will work using `cmd="date"`. But if you have a longer command (for example `cmd="grep 'pattern' input_file.txt"`), then it will not work, as you need to split the different arguments of your command line. For this, use the `shlex` module: `shlex.split(cmd)` will return the appropriate sequence to subprocess.

So, the code for your cmd_simulator would be something like:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

def cmd_simulator(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd))
```

And of course, you can add to this function some try/except to check that the command is working, etc.

If you don't only need the stdout of your command but also stderr for example, then you should use `subprocess.Popen(cmd)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method-

```
import subprocess

cmd_arg = "date"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_arg,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = proc.communicate()

print(out) #Thu Jan 28 12:18:05 EST 2016
```